# Can socialslots use variables?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

When using social forwards in an RSS feed email, can socialslots be used for each item in the feed (so instead of literally naming an area, can variables be used)?

```
<!-- RegionStart[ socialslot:"Shared content region 1",

title:"First shared email content",

description:"This is an example of shared content",

csskey:"portfolio css 1"] -->


<a href="%%=GetSocialPublishURL('1','Shared content region 1')=%%" alias="Social Forward to ShareThis - SharePasteHTML" title="Publish to ShareThis"><img src="Go to your Portfolio/Social Forward Folder and copy URL for the Social Forward Icon" alt="ShareThis" border="0" title="Insert Title Here"></a>
```

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/social_forward/